# Why do Spanish and other Romance Languages use the preposition "a" for culinary styles?

Tags: spanish, french, italian, prepositions

I've looked in the [Real Academia Española dictionary](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=a) and I can't find any information regarding why Spanish uses the preposition `a` for cooking styles, and I've noticed French and Italian do it too. I know that the languages use the word, but I don't understand how in a broad sense outside of cuisine.

- `fajitas a la parilla` (Spanish)
- `mojo al ajo` (Spanish)
- `escargots à la bourguignonne` (French)
- `spaghetti alla carbonara` (Italian)

In what sense is the `a` being used here?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic here. If you ask the same question on the Spanish site, for example, the answer will apply to all romance languages. Besides, this question is more about language use than linguistics per se.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115381/%c3%a0-la-masculine

Comment: It's not "a", it's "a la", "al", "à la", "alla". These are all preposition + definite particle differing only by language and gender.

Comment: @hippietrail, do you mean "article"? Add number to the list, e.g. "spaghetti aux moules".

Comment: @dainichi: Yes sorry, I made a typo I now can't fix \-:

Comment: I feel like the construction is even more curious now.

Comment: Good question! As a native speaker, ashamed I had never pondered that myself! Don't Portuguese or Catalan do this as well? Good be interesting to cross-post this question to one of those languages' sites, to see if someone can answer it - most likely, it'd aply for the others as well.

Answer (score 3):

In French, dishes "à la" stands for "à la façon de" which you could translate as "in the style of". So, "à la bourguignonne" means as it's done in that area of France.

Same idea for the other languages.

But sometimes the words "à la", "au", or "aux" point to some ingredients. For example: in "Courgettes farcies au saumon", the last part indicates that salmon is stuffed into the zucchinis.

Comment: "à la" does indeed mean "à la façon de", but "au", or "aux" refer to ingredients or accompaniments. These are two entirely different constructions.

Comment: Very true fdb. I have edited the first part of my answer to reflect your remark. The second part stands as one can say "lapin à la moutarde".